# I have created a data class for my table which is throwing error in named queries

Tags: java, jpa, entity

Entity name is similar to name of the table.

```
@Table
@Entity(name = "CKYCUploadTransactions")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@NamedQueries({
       @NamedQuery(name = "CKYCUploadTransactions.byUserId", query = "select k from CKYCUploadTransactions k where" +
               "k.userId = :user_id"),
       @NamedQuery(name = "CKYCUploadTransactions.byUserIdAndTxnTypeAndStatus", query = "select k from CKYCUploadTransactions k where" +
               "k.userId = :user_id AND k.txnType = :txn_type AND k.status = :status"),
       @NamedQuery(name = "CKYCUploadTransactions.byUserIdAndContext", query = "select k from CKYCUploadTransactions k where" +
               "k.userId = :user_id and k.context = :context")
})
@Data
public class CKYCUploadTransactions {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "context")
    private String context;

    @Column(name = "txn_type")
    private String txnType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", length = 20)
    private Status status;

    public enum Status{
        initiated,
        success,
        failed
    }

}
```

I am not understanding why it is throwing this error, I have created another entity like this but not facing the issues there.

Exception: Errors in named queries: CKYCUploadTransactions.byUserIdAndTxnTypeAndStatus, CKYCUploadTransactions.byUserIdAndContext, CKYCUploadTransactions.byUserId

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [JPA Named Queries](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named)

`CKYCUploadTransactions.byUserId`
should be
`CKYCUploadTransactions.findByUserId`